# RtControl showing 'never' for completion time for every torrent

Tags: rtorrent

I'm trying to use RtControl to automatically delete torrents older than a certain amount of time. However, my command isn't working, and when I try either `rtcontrol -q -o completed \*` or `rtcontrol -q -o loaded \*` both show 'never' for every single torrent, even though they're all completed, as confirmed by `rtcontrol is_complete=yes`. I'm using ruTorrent to manage rTorrent, could that be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You need the standard config included (so you have the finished event handler), and fix the times for any existing items, [as per the docs](http://pyrocore.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup.html#extending-your-rtorrent-rc).

```
#
# PyroScope SETTINGS
#

# Set "pyro.extended" to 1 to activate rTorrent-PS features!
# LEAVE THIS AT 0 IF YOU RUN A VANILLA rTorrent!
system.method.insert = pyro.extended, value|const, 0

# Set "pyro.bin_dir" to the "bin" directory where you installed the pyrocore tools!
# Make sure you end it with a "/"; if this is left empty, then the shell's path is searched.
system.method.insert = pyro.bin_dir, string|const,

# Remove the ".default" if you want to change something (else your
# changes get over-written on update).
system.method.insert = pyro.rc_dialect, string|const|simple, "execute_capture=bash,-c,\"test $1 = 0.8.6 && echo -n 0.8.6 || echo -n 0.8.9\",dialect,$system.client_version="
system.method.insert = pyro.rtorrent_rc, string|const|private, "$cat=~/.pyroscope/rtorrent-,\"$pyro.rc_dialect=\",.rc.default"
import = $pyro.rtorrent_rc=

# TORQUE: Daemon watchdog schedule
# Must be activated by touching the "~/.pyroscope/run/pyrotorque" file!
# Set the second argument to "-v" or "-q" to change log verbosity.
schedule = pyro_watchdog,30,300,"pyro.watchdog=~/.pyroscope,"
```